# Calculate APR (annual percentage rate) Programmatically

Tags: objective-c, algorithm

I am trying to find a way to programmatically calculate APR based on

- Total Loan Amount
- Payment Amount
- Number of payments
- Repayment frequency

There is no need to take any fees into account.

It's ok to assume a fixed interest rate, and any remaining amounts can be rolled into the last payment.

The formula below is based on a credit  agreement  for  a  total  amount  of  credit  of  €6000  repayable  in  24  equal  monthly instalments of €274.11.

[image]

(The APR for the above example is 9.4%)

I am looking for an algorithm in any programming language that I can adapt to C.

Comment: I am going to be implementing it in objective c, but I will be happy with an answer in any language.

Comment: Another question: APR methodologies can vary wildly depending on the full requirements.  A simple thing is whether or not you need to take balloon payments into account.  Also, what happens with the left over pennies?  Are they folded into the final payment or somehow spread across the last couple?  Do you have to take a variable interest rate into account (like ARM loans)?  How are various fees handled?  In short, what are your full requirements and what have you tried?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annual_percentage_rate

Comment: Another helpful tidbit is what APR would you expect for the example you provided?

Comment: pmg's reference is the best place to get started.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I have updated my question to include the things you mentioned. I believe the APR for the above example is 9.4%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you want to compute `X` from your equation. This equation can be written as

```
f(y) = y + y**2 + y**3 + ... + y**N - L/P = 0
```

where

```
X = APR
L = Loan (6000)
P = Individual Payment (274.11)
N = Number of payments (24)
F = Frequency (12 per year)
y = 1 / ((1 + X)**(1/F))   (substitution to simplify the equation)
```

Now, you need to solve the equation `f(y) = 0` to get `y`. This can be done e.g. using the Newton's iteration (pseudo-code):

```
y = 1  (some plausible initial value)
repeat 
    dy = - f(y) / f'(y)
    y += dy
until abs(dy) < eps
```

The derivative is:

```
f'(y) = 1 + 2*y + 3*y**2 + ... + N*y**(N-1)
```

You would compute `f(y)` and `f'(y)` using the Horner rule for polynomials to avoid the exponentiation. The derivative can be likely approximated by some few first terms. After you find `y`, you get `x`:

```
x = y**(-F) - 1
```

Comment: That looks great - what does eps represent?

Comment: eps is a small quantity, e.g. 1e-6. The solution is approximated with the maximal absolute error eps. You would need to try out what is a suitable eps in your case.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Objective C code snippet I came up with (which seems to be correct) if anybody is interested:

```
float x = 1;
do{
    fx = initialPaymentAmt+paymentAmt *(pow(x, numPayments+1)-x)/(x-1)+0*pow(x,numPayments)-totalLoanAmt;
    dx = paymentAmt *(numPayments * pow( x , numPayments + 1 ) - ( numPayments + 1 )* pow(x,numPayments)+1) / pow(x-1,2)+numPayments * 0 * pow(x,numPayments-1);
    z = fx / dx;
    x=x-z;
} while (fabs(z)>1e-9 ); 

apr=100*(pow(1/x,ppa)-1);
```

Comment: Hi Ben I am looking for the same formula. What is ppa here?

Comment: Hi Nilesh, it's been a while since I wrote this! but I think ppa was number of payments per annum.